# My textFields doesn't disappear when is invoked viewWillAppear method in swift

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SystemConfiguration

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var simpleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var uiNameSearch: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var uiGivenName: UITextField!
    var patient1 = Patient!()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        uiNameSearch.delegate = self
        uiGivenName.delegate = self

        print("ViewController viewDidLoad")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.simpleLabel.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
        self.uiGivenName.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
        print("Call viewWillAppear")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9 , animations: {
           // self.simpleLabel.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
            self.uiGivenName.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        })

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7 , delay: 0.7, options: [], animations: {
            self.uiNameSearch.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        }, completion: nil )
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func searchForName(sender: UIButton) {
        let header = ["Accept" : "application/json"]
        let name = uiNameSearch.text!
        let given = uiGivenName.text!
        if name.characters.count == 0 {
            self.view.makeToast( message: "Please insert the family name of the patient!")
        } else  if given.characters.count == 0 {
            self.view.makeToast(message: "Please insert the patient given name!")
        } else if checkInternetConnection() == false {
            self.view.makeToast(message: "Please connect to the internet!")
        } else {
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://open-ic.epic.com/FHIR/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Patient?family=\(name)&given=\(given)", headers: header).responseJSON { response in
                self.patient1 = Patient(response: response.result.value!)
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSegue", sender: sender)

            }
        }
    }

    func checkInternetConnection() -> Bool {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }
        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        switch textField {
        case uiNameSearch:
            uiNameSearch.resignFirstResponder()
            uiGivenName.becomeFirstResponder()

        case uiGivenName:
            uiGivenName.resignFirstResponder()

        default:
            print("")
        }
        return true
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?){
        if segue.identifier == "showSegue" {
            if let displayViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DisplayViewController {
                displayViewController.patient1 = patient1
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I want to make uiGivenName and simpleLabel to disappear until the view is created and after when the viewDidAppear is invoked to appear from the left side.

Comment: are your outlets (e.g. `uiNameSearch`) connected up to your view controller in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes of curse they are connected to the view controller in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Your view doesn't disappear because you are changing position of views in viewWillAppear and when viewWillAppear gets called, view is about to be added to view hierarchy(i.e view is still not added to view hierarchy.), so its not reflecting in your UI.

So you can do your stuff in viewDidLayoutSubviews because this is the best place if you want to modify your UI just before it actually appears in the screen.

Edit -

Replace this -

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.simpleLabel.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    self.uiGivenName.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    print("Call viewWillAppear")
}
```

with

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.simpleLabel.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    self.uiGivenName.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
}
```

Comment: You don't understand my question, the uiGivenName should come from the left side when the view is initialized

Comment: I have explained that only, just check the edit, I have added code. Just move your code inside viewWillAppear to viewDidLayoutSubviews as shown in edited answer, and you will get your desired result i.e uiGivenName will come from left.

Comment: I will test it monday ani I will come with an answer. Hope it works!

Comment: It works perfectly can you explain me what viewDidLayoutSubviews() did exactly; and why it doesn't work with viewWillAppear. Thanks!

Comment: It is a problem, when I want to introduce the name, name fields disappear.

Comment: I have explained in the above answer, try reading it once again, but here I am giving some more information on view Controllers life cycle. 

viewWillAppear - Gets called when the view controller's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy. (Note -the view is yet to be added to the view hierarchy).

viewDidLayoutSubviews - Gets called when view controller just laid out its subviews. (Note - This is the place if you want to modify your UI just before appearing on screen.)
viewDidAppear - gets called when view controller's view was added to a view hierarchy.

Comment: For your second comment, I didn't get your problem, Can you expalin more.

Comment: When I want to introduce the name and push the TextField, textfield disappear. This is the problem

Comment: If I have understood your problem correctly just remove these lines 

 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7 , delay: 0.7, options: [], animations: {
            self.uiNameSearch.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        }, completion: nil )
from your code , your textField will not disappear.

If still your problem is not solved, post screenshot of the effect you want to achieve then it will be easy to understand your problem and help.

Comment: No. my problem is persisting